# Create .step list based on another parameter

Tags: ltspice

**Problem:**

I'm trying to create a `.step list` of values based on another parameter but none of the syntax I've tried seems to work.

**Example:**

In the voltage divider below, I'd like to step the values of `R2` in multiples (1x, 1.5x, 2x) of `R1`. I can do this manually for a given `R1` but I'd like to be able to vary `R1` and still have the `.step` values of `R2` calculated by LTspice.

Both of the forms I tried yield the same error message:

> Syntax error in .step command (2nd dimension)

[image]

**Related:**

[LTSpice - Printing resultant parameters based on expressions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/105535/128715) looks similar, but using single quotes doesn't work either.

**Question:**

Is there a way to do this? If so, what's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple method:**

It is possible to achieve the results posited by *Ste Kulov* even without using an independent voltage source. All that is needed is a single parameter, which can be defined in the `.step` directive and referenced directly.

As per *Ste Kulov's* comment below:

> *Since you don't need the voltage source then you don't even need the behavioral resistor. It's always better to use a regular resistor whenever possible. So I would replace the `R=R1*multiplier` with `{R1*multiplier}` so a regular resistor is used.*

Putting it all together we get:

[image: Stepping Component Value]

**Note:** the `.param multiplier=0` is commented out in this case. If you have a programmer's mindset you might want to have it in there as a directive (i.e. uncommented) just to be pedantic... but it's not required, `.step` will override the initialisation value anyway.

*Ste Kulov's* answer was as an essential stepping stone in figuring this out. It just seemed too convoluted to define a voltage source with the sole purpose of acting as an input parameter. So I tried to eliminate this additional step and got lucky. Thanks a bunch, *Ste Kulov*!

Comment: Duh.  Of course!  Good job.  I can't believe my brain overlooked this and over-complicated the solution.  My bad.  Since you don't need the voltage source then you don't even need the behavioral resistor.  It's always better to use a regular resistor whenever possible.  So I would replace the `R=R1*multiplier` with `{R1*multiplier}` so a regular resistor is used.  You should definitely accept this answer once the timeout period expires.

Comment: I've just edited in your further excellent suggestions. Thanks for helping me piece this together!

Comment: No problem!  Glad I was able to help.

Comment: Oh ya.  Just noticed the new photo still shows the `R=`.  You have to get rid of that so the behavioral resistor is not used.  It should look like this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEKy2.png

Comment: @SteKulov Ach, well spotted! ... and now corrected too. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your general usage of curly braces is incorrect as it should be: `.step param R2 list {R1} {R1*1.5} {R1*2}`.  But it doesn't matter since you cannot evaluate expressions within a `.step` command, so you'll always get those syntax errors.  You either need to make multiple copies of your circuit, or create a behavioral resistor which can evaluate the resistance based on other information on your circuit.

Here is one such way to do it.  Independent voltage source V1 is stepped through `1`, `1.5`, and `2` and the behavioral resistor is evaluated as R1 multiplied by the value of the node at the top of the voltage source: `R=R1*V(step)`

[image]

You can also step the independent voltage source directly without using a `param` as follows.  Just like a `.dc` sweep, you need to give the voltage source a default value (I simply picked zero).

[image]

Comment: Please vote for the other answer.  This one is bad.  LOLE.